# filter xss/scripting from input field

Tags: php

I have a form:

```
<form class="search" id="searchName" action="results.php" method="GET">
      <div class="container-search">
           <input type="text" id="wifiname" placeholder="WiFi name" name="wifiname"> <!-- input -->
           <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>
</form>
```

that I am using the `$_GET['wifiname']` and searching through the database. However I am trying to remove any chance for a script being submitted in this input field. I have some php which searches through the database depending on the input, and have made an effort of trying to `trim/stripslashes/htmlspecialchars` the input before searching:

```
// Search by WifiName
if (isset($_GET["wifiname"])) {
    $wifiname = $_GET["wifiname"];
    $wifiname = trim($wifiname);
    $wifiname = stripslashes($wifiname);
    $wifiname = htmlspecialchars($wifiname);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE wifiName LIKE :wifiname;";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindValue(':wifiname', '%' . $wifiname . '%');
    $q->execute();

    $nRows = $q->rowCount();
    if ($nRows == 1) {
        echo "<p>" . $nRows . " result found from search...</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>" . $nRows . " results found from search...</p>";
    }
} else {
    $wifiname = null;
}
```

However, when submitting it is outputting: `results.php?wifiname=<script>alert%28"Hacked"%29<%2Fscript>` when I enter `<script>alert("Hacked")</script>` into the input field. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: can anyone help?

Comment: well, because your countermeasure is only.. on the query.. it does not prevent you from having such query string..

Comment: You are running `htmlspecialchars` over some data just before you put it in a database. A database is not an HTML document! So don't do that! You might be planning to take the data out of the database and put it in an HTML document, you should use `htmlspecialchars` then. If you were, for example, to decide to put the data in an email as well, then you would have a whole bunch of HTML source code that you would have to convert back to plain text!

Comment: It looks like you are storing data about WIFI SSIDs in a database. The ```\``` character is a valid character in an SSSID. **Do not use `stripslashes` here!**. (For that matter, don't use it anywhere, there are almost always more appropriate routines to use).

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens

1. User enters data into form
2. Browser converts the data in the form into a URL
3. Browser navigates to that URL
4. PHP receives data in the URL
5. PHP modifies that data
6. PHP uses that modified data in a database query

You are looking at the URL in the address bar, which is the state of the state at step 3.

Your code isn't doing anything with it until step 5.

This is not a problem.

Comment: so my approach to the problem is wrong. if we pretend I only have the form and wanted to implement a php solution to this when submitting the form, could you help direct me?

Comment: @CeraMix — "so my approach to the problem is wrong" — I refer you back to the last sentence of my answer.